# Synchronization between instances of the Office Word JavaScript add-in

Tags: javascript, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I'm working on JavaScript add-in for Office Word (Win10 and Mac) and store some shared data in [`OfficeRuntime.storage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-runtime/officeruntime.storage?view=excel-js-preview) (open for suggestions about other global persistent storages). Add-in displays this data on taskpane. Currently, if a user changes this data though one instance, it won't affect other add-in instances (e.g. in other open documents) until the taskpane is reopened or the add-in re-reads the data manually.

**Is there a way to notify active add-in instances about changes in storage?**

I tried HTML5 storage but it pickups values only once when add-in initialized. The Storage Event didn't work in add-in at all. I also don't want to pool storage each N amount of time and I don't want to use some third party servers (e.g. with websocket) to achieve it.

Any suggestions on how to sync two different instances of add-in? Maybe the Office product team already working on something similar?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to achieve through the [SharedRuntime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime#about-the-shared-javascript-runtime) which is currently available for Excel and PowerPoint. But, according to a comment from AbidRahman-MSFT, the Office team have plans on bringing shared runtime for Word within the next 6 months.
More here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1671